# How do I solve int cannot be converted to int[]?

Tags: java, methods

I created a java program for a board game called Mastermind. I have created the class called Mastermind and called it in the my main method. I tried inputting numbers from the array I created but it giving me an error of it unable to find the symbol when I tried calling Mastermind. I switched it something else after and stated it as guessResult = Mastermind.attempt(guess[2]); .  Now I have an error of  int cannot be converted to int[]?, how do I solve this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MastermindGame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //game instructions
        System.out.print("Welcome to Mastermind!");
        System.out.print("The computer will generate a passcode with your specified number of digits.");
        System.out.print("Your job is to break that code!");
        System.out.print("After each guess, the computer will tell you how many correct digits are in the correct position.");
        System.out.print("It will do this by printing one X for each correct digit.");
        System.out.print("It does not tell you which digit is correct.");
        System.out.println("If you do not see any Xs print, none of your digits were correct.");
        System.out.println("GOOD LUCK!");
        
        //ask user to determine how many digits the code will be
        System.out.println("How many digits would you like the code to be?");
        //enable input from the user
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //read the integer the user types
        int length = in.nextInt();
        //create the new game with the indicated number of digits
        Mastermind game = new Mastermind(length);
        
        //ssshh!! cheating so we can see if this works!
        System.out.println("Shhh! Just so we know if our program works, the code is ");
        game.printCode();
        
        //set up an array to hold the user's guesses
        int[] guess = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        
        //set up a String to display the result of the guess
        String guessResult = " ";
        
                
        //allow the user 4 tries to break the code
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            //tell the user to take a guess
            System.out.println("Gander a guess");
            //loops as many digits (length) as they indicated the code should be
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                //ask the user to input their guess for this digit
                System.out.println(" What is the next digit for the code");
                //store their guess in the guess array
                guess[i] = in.nextInt();
            }
            //call the method in the Mastermind class that checks their guess against the code
            guessResult = Mastermind(2);
            //it will print out as many Xs as correct digits, order irrelevant
            System.out.println ( guessResult);
            
            //if the user guess, game over so end the main method with "return"
            if (guessResult.equals("YOU WIN!!"))
                return;
        }
        //if we get outside the loop, user wasn't able to guess, "game over"
        System.out.println("~~~GAME OVER~~~");
    }
}

class Mastermind
{
    private int[] code;
    
    //overloaded constructor
    public Mastermind(int length)
    {
        //get the length of the array to the number of digits the user requested
        code = new int[length];
        
        //walk through the code
        for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++)
        {
            //add a random digit (0-2 in this case) to the code
            code[i] =  (int)(Math.random()*3 + 0);
        }
    }
    
    //method to check the user's guess against the code
    public String attempt(int[] guess)
    {
        String response = "";
        boolean verify = true;
        
        //walk through the guess array
        for (int k = 4; k < 4; k++)
        {
            //compare guess array to code
            //if digits are the same, add an X to response string
            if (code == guess)
               response += "X";
            //if digits are not equal, set verify to false because the guess is not the code
            else
                verify = false;
        }
        
        //if verify was never set to false, then the user guessed correctly so return YOU WIN
        if ( guess== code)
            return "YOU WIN!!";
        
        //if code gets here, user did not guess correctly, return the String with Xs for correct number of digits.
        return "X";
    }
    
    //created this method so we can cheat to check that our game works
    public void printCode()
    {
        String answer = "";
        //walk through code, concatenating the digit to the answer string
        for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++)
        {
            answer += code[i] + " ";
        }
        //print the code
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend reading some java tutorials

Comment: I'll give you a hint -  its this line - guessResult = Mastermind(2);

Comment: Add to your question the complete error, with all lines.

Comment: `Mastermind.attempt(guess[2]);` - what do you think this is doing?  attempt method is expecting an array, and you are passing in a single int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a functional version of your code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MastermindGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // game instructions
        System.out.println("Welcome to Mastermind!");
        System.out.println("The computer will generate a passcode with your specified number of digits.");
        System.out.println("Your job is to break that code!");
        System.out.println("After each guess, the computer will tell you how many correct digits are in the correct position.");
        System.out.println("It will do this by printing one X for each correct digit.");
        System.out.println("It does not tell you which digit is correct.");
        System.out.println("If you do not see any Xs print, none of your digits were correct.");
        System.out.println("GOOD LUCK!");

        // ask user to determine how many digits the code will be
        System.out.println("How many digits would you like the code to be?");
        // enable input from the user
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        // read the integer the user types
        int length = in.nextInt();
        // create the new game with the indicated number of digits
        Mastermind game = new Mastermind(length);

        // ssshh!! cheating so we can see if this works!
        System.out.print("Shhh! Just so we know if our program works, the code is ");
        game.printCode();

        // set up an array to hold the user's guesses
        int[] guess = new int[length];

        // allow the user 4 tries to break the code
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            // tell the user to take a guess
            System.out.println("Gander a guess");
            // loops as many digits (length) as they indicated the code should be
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                // ask the user to input their guess for this digit
                System.out.print(" What is the next digit for the code?\n  ");
                // store their guess in the guess array
                guess[i] = in.nextInt();
            }

            // call the method in the Mastermind class that checks their guess against the code
            int guessResult = game.attempt(guess);
            if (guessResult < 0) {
                System.out.println("YOU WIN!!");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < guessResult; i++)
                    System.out.print("X");
                System.out.print("\n\n");
            }
        }
        // if we get outside the loop, user wasn't able to guess, "game over"
        System.out.println("~~~GAME OVER~~~");
    }
}

class Mastermind {
    private final int[] code;

    // overloaded constructor
    public Mastermind(int length) {
        //get the length of the array to the number of digits the user requested
        code = new int[length];

        // walk through the code
        for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
            //add a random digit (0-2 in this case) to the code
            code[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 0);
        }
    }

    // method to check the user's guess against the code
    public int attempt(int[] guess) {
        if (Arrays.equals(guess, code)) {
            // Return -1 if the player win
            return -1;
        } else {
            int correctDigits = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
                if (code[i] == guess[i]) {
                    correctDigits++;
                }
            }
            return correctDigits;
        }
    }

    // created this method, so we can cheat to check that our game works
    public void printCode() {
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        // walk through code, concatenating the digit to the answer string
        for (int j : code) {
            answer.append(j);
            answer.append(" ");
        }
        // Remove the last space
        String answerString = answer.substring(0, answer.length() - 1);
        // print the code
        System.out.println(answerString);
    }
}
```